# Can't duplicate layout look in XML resource file through Java

Tags: java, android, sdk

I'm new to Android development. I searched the web for an answer, but coming up empty. I'm trying to create rows in a TableLayout dynamically that looks like what I have in my XML below:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.example.me.testdesign.MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="345dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#12dd12"
                android:text="static textview"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="static btn"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:background="#12dd12"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This XML file gives the look I want for each row, as pictured in the snapshot below:

[image]

Below is the Java code to create an additional row dynamically:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show(); }
            });

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tvlparams =
                new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        tvlparams.weight = 3;
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(0xff12dd12);
        tv.setText("dynamic textview");
        tv.setLayoutParams(tvlparams);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams btnlparams =
                new TableLayout.LayoutParams( 0, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        btnlparams.weight = 2;
        btnlparams.rightMargin = 10;
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("dynamic btn");
        btn.setBackgroundColor(0xff12dd12);
        btn.setLayoutParams(btnlparams);

        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.addView(tv);
        row.addView(btn);
        TableLayout TL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        TL.addView(row);
    }
}
```

The Java code above seems to do nothing! Why don't I get a new row?

However if I comment out `tv.setLayoutParams(tvlparams)` and `btn.setLayoutParams(btnlparams)` I get this:

[image]

What is going on? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The `Button` and `TextView` should have `TableRow.LayoutParams`, not `TableLayout.LayoutParams`. Also, their heights, and the `TableRow`'s height, should be `WRAP_CONTENT`, but that's not likely causing the current issue. You might also consider creating a separate layout file with your `TableRow` and its children already set up, so you'd just have to inflate it, and set values.

Comment: Yea that did it, thanks. So what is the principle? You need to apply the LayoutParams type of the parent control to the child?

Comment: Yeah, a `View`'s `LayoutParams` is the type of its direct parent, as its information for the parent on how to layout the child. In this case, `TableLayout.LayoutParams` just didn't convert appropriately to `TableRow.LayoutParams` when you added those `View`s. However, in other cases, it could cause a crash if the `LayoutParams` are not the right type.

Comment: @MikeM TableRow's height should be MATCH_PARENT since each cell element in the row should take up the row height.

Comment: @ruben The `TableRow`'s height definitely should not be `MATCH_PARENT`, unless you really only want to see one of them, but I'm pretty sure `TableLayout` would ignore that, anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. For a table row I have used `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` , where each row is actually using `WRAP_CONTENT`. But a `Button` and a `TextView` are cells in a row. So I need to set `TableRow.LayoutParams` (!) for each of them where they are using `MATCH_PARENT`. I have put my tested code as an answer but I still could be wrong..

Comment: @ruben Oh, you meant the `TableRow.LayoutParams` should have `MATCH_PARENT` height? Yeah, probably. I guess I didn't look at the expected image closely enough. Also, `TableRow` is a `LinearLayout`, so your `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` do work, in this case, since we're only specifying width and height.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* create textview */
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(0xff12dd12);
        tv.setText("dynamic textview");

        /* create button */
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("dynamic btn");
        btn.setBackgroundColor(0xff12dd12);

        TableRow.LayoutParams trparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        trparams.weight = 3;
        tv.setLayoutParams(trparams);
        trparams.weight = 2;
        trparams.rightMargin = 10;
        btn.setLayoutParams(trparams);

        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutTable);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        /* create a table row */
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

        /* add views to the row */
        tableRow.addView(tv);
        tableRow.addView(btn);

        /* add the row to the table */
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
```